# How do you add attribute validation to an LDAP schema?

Tags: ldap, schema

e.g.

```
attributetype ( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.39
    NAME 'preferredLanguage'
    DESC 'RFC2798: preferred written or spoken language for a person'
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
    SINGLE-VALUE )
```

I've read that I could add {4096} onto the end of the syntax to set a recommended length, but that some LDAP servers ignore it and none treat it like validation and it's not be used as a max? OpenLDAP is the implementation I'm tied to.

Is that correct? Is there a better way to add simple validation aspects - max and min length and not null ought to cover my use cases. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should consult the LDAP standards documentation: [RFC4512](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#section-4) is quite clear on this question:

```
for instance, "1.3.6.4.1.1466.0{64}" suggests
that server implementations should allow a string to be 64 characters
long, although they may allow longer strings.
```

The key words are: `suggest` and `may`.

As for `not-null`, the same admonition applies: consult the standards documentation to locate a directory schema syntax that does not allow for `null` octet strings.

Comment: That's very clear that what I've read already from there is as I've read it, it's less clear that I haven't missed some way of specifying an enforced constraint.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, then. If you are looking for a way to specify what sort of data can
be stored in an attribute value, then the attribute syntax (defined in the schema)  is where
those constraints are found. In some cases, such as the [UnboundID Server
SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/products/server-sdk.php), you can easily define a custom attribute
syntax to enforce whatever constraint meets your requirements.